# Why am I getting a Field Count Mismatch error after the first Fetch?

Tags: sql, db2, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have tried everything I can think of but I am still getting an error on the Fetch

I am looping through a multi-value field for each Select statement and need to store the return values in another multi-value field. It works for the first loop and then errors out on the Fetch the 2nd time through.

```
If lc_conn.IsConnected Then     
    For a = 0 To UBound(uniquePlans)            
        b = 0
        SelectStatement2 = "Select Count(CSSN) as counter From cbsdta.covgold where " &_
        " CEFFDT<" & todaysDate & " And (CTRMDT=0 Or CTRMDT>=" & todaysDate & ") And " &_
        "CDTASRC='GIAS' AND CABSGP='" & groupNo & "' AND CPRODTA='" & uniquePlans(a) & "'"
        
        Count2 = lc_conn.Execute(SelectStatement2, fldLstRecord2 )
        if Count2 <> 0 then

            While (LC_Conn.Fetch( fldLstRecord2 ) > 0) '<---- Error here on 2nd loop

                redim Preserve CoveredLives(b)
                Set CoveredLives(b) = fldLstRecord2.Lookup("counter").value
                b = b + 1
            Wend
        End if
    Next
    doc.CoveredLives = CoveredLives
End If
```

All ideas or suggestions appreciated

Comment: I may be missing some facts, but your result set will have at most one row with one column, because you are selecting a COUNT(CSSN). A single fetch would return that scalar value, if it exists.   I would expect a second fetch to throw an exception.

Comment: Exactly what I said. I can get the count for the first value and then it fails on the 2nd. DO you have any suggestions as to how to get it to NOT fail on the 2nd and all subsequent loops?

Comment: Is the error on the second iteration of the FOR loop, or of the WHILE loop?

Comment: print text to an output log to see where the script is failing

Comment: I know where it is failing and I stated it in multiple places in my question and in the code. I can watch it on the server console and have print statements on every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to clear fldListRecord2 using a ‘Delete fldListRecord2’ command within the the loop. Once I added that, everything worked. I also had to Dim the LCFieldList within the loop to reinitialize it each time through.

```
If lc_conn.IsConnected Then
    ReDim Preserve CoveredLives(UBound(uniquePlans))        
    For a = 0 To UBound(uniquePlans)
        Dim fldLstRecord2 As New LCFieldList            
        If (lc_conn.Execute ("Select Count(CSSN) as counter From cbsdta.covgold where " &_
        " CEFFDT < " & todaysDate & " And (CTRMDT = 0 Or CTRMDT > " & todaysDate & ") And " &_
        "CDTASRC = 'GIAS' AND CABSGP = '" & groupNo & "' AND CPRODTA = '" & Right(uniquePlans(a),7) & "'", fldLstRecord2) <> 0) Then            
        End If          
        Set fld = fldLstRecord2.Lookup ("counter")
        While (lc_conn.Fetch(fldLstRecord2) > 0)                
            CoveredLives(a) = fld.text(0)                
            Delete fldLstRecord2
        Wend            
    Next        
    doc.CoveredLives = CoveredLives     
End If
```

Thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 1):

According to [example](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_971389FETCH_METHOD_FOR_LCCONNECTION.html?hl=lcfieldlist%2Cvalue%2Cfetch) in HCL's documentation, `Lookup` is used outside the `Fetch` loop. Try this:

```vb
       Dim fieldCounter As LCField
...

       Set fieldCounter = fldLstRecord2.Lookup("counter")
       While (LC_Conn.Fetch( fldLstRecord2 ) > 0) 
            redim Preserve CoveredLives(b)
            Set CoveredLives(b) = fieldCounter.value(0)
            b = b + 1
       Wend
```

LCField's `value` returns always an array of values so you should use `.value(0)`.